# jQuery Event Does Not Toggle Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I want to make a discount system based on Dollar and Percentage. So I made this form:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col">
        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        <label for="type" class="control-label">Type of discount</label>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="type">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="type">
                Dollar
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="type" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="type">
                Percentage
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col">
        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        <label for="value" class="control-label">Value of dicount</label>
        <small id="typepercent">percentage</small>
        <small id="typedollar">dollars</small>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="value" name="value" class="form-control" value="" autofocus>
    </div>
</div>
```

So basically users can choose the discount type between **Dollar** type or **Percentage** type.

Then at the next input, they have to write the value of discount. If they have selected Percentage, this text must be appears:

`<small id="typepercent">percentage</small>`

Otherwise, show this:

`<small id="typedollar">dollars</small>`

Now in order to do this, I added this script:

```
const typedis = document.querySelector('#type');
typedis.addEventListener('change', e => {
      if(e.target.checked === true) {
            $("#typepercent").hide();
            $('#typedollar').show();
      }else{
            $("#typepercent").show();
            $('#typedollar').hide();
      }
});
```

But now it does not work out properly!

I mean the first time when I changes to Dollar, it shows `#typedollar` correctly but when I go back to Percentage, the `#typedollar` div still shows up however it must be hidden and `#typepercent` must be appear.

So what's going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: why are you mixing jquery and vanilla javascript?

Comment: also, you cannot use the same `id="type"` for many `input`. it is a unique attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use the same id for multiple elements. You just need to use simple jquery and add a class in your radio input elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
   $('.form-check-input').on("change", function(){
      if($(this).hasClass("dollar")) {
            $("#typepercent").hide();
            $('#typedollar').show();
      }else{
            $("#typepercent").show();
            $('#typedollar').hide();
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col">
        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        <label for="type" class="control-label">Type of discount</label>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input dollar" type="radio" name="type" id="type">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="type">
                Dollar
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input percentage" type="radio" name="type" id="type" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="type">
                Percentage
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col">
        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        <label for="value" class="control-label">Value of dicount</label>
        <small id="typepercent">percentage</small>
        <small id="typedollar">dollars</small>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="value" name="value" class="form-control" value="" autofocus>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```